# Output() in fpdf does not work

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to generate a pdf file containing pie charts. By i am having the following Error:

**FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file**

After fighting for about an hour I found out that it works pretty well with: *Output("Report.pdf",'F');* but shows error message with: *Output();*.

So I am stuck here...can anyone help me with this situation ?

Comment: You're sending some data to browser before calling Output() , thats the problem, you could paste your php script on pastebin.com and paste the link here so we can look at where are you doing the mistake.

Comment: its not only about echoing but also of output buffers.if the contents of buffer contains characters other than UTF-8 BOM and/or whitespace, it will throw the exact error.

Comment: @itachi-Actually it contains a Pie Chart..so can it be the problem..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the following at the start of your php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

that will avoid `E_WARNING` errors to be outputted, without looking at the code for a proper fix, this could help.

Comment: @itachi-This is the script http://pastie.org/private/cyyml88ju3ewbu12jxumq..Now can u tell whats the error...

Comment: All the variables like $arraygrabber, $num_users generating correct vales which are purely alphabets...I doubt the PieChart functon.

Comment: I have not found any error on that code, so make sure you don't have spaces before the "<?php" tag , because they will affect output.

Comment: @Nelson-I checked that first !! If u can observe than it shows error in _checkoutput(); function in fpdf.php which is I think it contains more than  only a UTF-8 BOM and/or whitespace. But what is thesolution to that ?!!

Comment: Oh I see, but that is not the real error, that is only FPDF telling you it detected output already sent.. you have to check where that output is generated

Comment: To check that, when browser says "FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file" do right click and "Show source code for this page", paste that source to pastie, in it you can find the error.

Comment: @Nelson-No luck dude...but I think I got the result, and it works pretty fine. So I should move to better stuff. Thanks a  lot dude for helping me out !!

Comment: @Nelson- Couldnt do anything else until I found error!! To my surprise it is in http://pastie.org/4780119

Comment: That line is correct, so probably that is not line 46 (PHP can count lines differently).. If you paste your view.php file I could try to find the culprit.

Comment: This is my complete view.php script :- http://pastie.org/private/6vmvgd0xk5pbxxbjvsmcpa

Comment: From a quick look, it could be "$row111 = $piece[1];" try replacing it for "$row111 = isset($piece[1]) ? $piece[1] : '';" and you have another similar line.

Answer (score 1):

You have already echoing something, so your httpresponse has already a header that says "I am a html text response", you can't modify it to say you are *also* a pdf response. You have to chose wether you output only html (so you profide a filename as argument of the output function so that you can generate a link to access to your pdf) or you output only pdf by removing any echo, printf or outside

Comment: @artragis-There is neither 'echo' nor 'print' statement in my script..I alredy khew that..can u suggest something else..?? Thanks for reply

Comment: so if yhere is no echo, you forgot a parasite "new line" char after a ?> in your script.

Answer (score 0):

[Output](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)

Output accept second parameter

```
I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
S: return the document as a string. name is ignored.
```

Comment: Yup I know that.I want to do it with 'I', which is by default with Output();. But it shows error..But some how its possible with Output("",'F');.